# What is the value of f(x)?

Tags: probability

Here is a probability mass function $f(x)$ for a discrete random variable $X$ assuming values $x=0,1,\dots, 15$. $f(x)=\frac{16-x}{2x}f(x-1)$ for $x=0,1,\dots, 15$ and zero elsewhere.Then can we find the value of $f(x)$? I have no idea how to do this. :(
Thank you!

Comment: $ $ $\sum f(x)=1$

Comment: Since the function is a probability mass function we know what the sum of its values must add up to one: $$\sum_{x=0}^{15} f(x) = 1$$

Comment: yes, but what next?

Comment: what is $f(-1)$?

Comment: Given $f(0)$, the formula allows you  to compute $f(x)$ in terms of $f(0)$. Then @mergeme's comment allows you to compute $f(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(0)=c$.

Then $f(1)= \frac{15}{2}c$.

And $f(2) = \frac{14}{4}\cdot\frac{15}{2}c$.

And $f(3) = \frac{13}{6}\cdot\frac{14}{4}\cdot\frac{15}{2}c$.

And so on.  When you've reached $f(15)$, you can then figure out what $c$ has to be to make them add up to $1$.

This is a plodding pedestrian way to do the problem.  A slicker way might exploit patterns.  Maybe you'll see some patterns as you procede.

But at least this is a way to see that it can be done.

Later note: . . . . for example, $f(3) = \frac{1}{2^3}\binom{15}{3}c$.  And this hints that the binomial theorem can be used.